# C++ always use checked_cast instead of static_cast?

Tags: c++, casting

When I read about C++ casting operators, I see generally see 4 types of casts for example here:
[Cast types](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_casting_operators.htm)

```
const_cast
dynamic_cast
reinterpret_cast
static_cast
```

But what about `checked_cast` as described here
[checked_cast](https://mikejsavage.co.uk/blog/cpp-tricks-better-casting.html)

Should we always use `checked_cast` instead of `static_cast` as a rule of thumb?

Comment: Do you know what `dynamic_cast` does? What `const_cast` does? How do you propose to use this "checked_cast" instead of them?

Comment: That implementation is not zero cost, so I would consider it case by case. See also `gsl::narrow_cast` and [CppCoreGuidelines P.4](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#p4-ideally-a-program-should-be-statically-type-safe)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It does `const_cast` just fine, in fact it is modelling a C style cast: https://godbolt.org/z/5WGzdaK7z, which I wouldn't consider a good thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`checked_cast` only replaces `static_cast`.

That article assumes that you never want a lossy conversion. If you have a `float` and *want* the largest `int` not larger than that, `checked_cast` is incorrect.

It also assumes that the conversion goes both ways. If it doesn't then it's ill formed.

Comment: Actually, since it uses `T(from)`, which is equivalent to an explicit cast `(T)from`, it does all of the conversions, except `dynamic_cast`, which makes it rather unsafe.